# Creating unique column in .sql script (asp.net core)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [User](
   UserId int identity(1,1),
   Email varchar(max) unique not null,
   UserName varchar(30) unique not null,
   [Password] varchar(max)not null,
   PRIMARY KEY(UserId)
);
```

When I run this script I get an error saying that Email and UserName are of invalid types for unique constraint.  So my question is **how can I create a unique column in table script?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) as unique values.. Please consider setting the length of these columns to a lower value.

I think the max length you can use for unique for nvarchars is 450

Passwords and e-mails shouldn't be very long anyway, perhaps 100 length should be more than enough.

Anyway, just dont use max if you want it to be a unique column.

Personally, I think you don't have to enforce passwords to be unique. A user might know if the password is being used by another account if his password is not accepted.

Comment: I wasn't enforcing passwords to be unique, just the Email and UserName :b.  Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: oh it was on the username, sorry. i thought the unique constraint was also on the password. Thanks! @j3ssi3ftw